# How can I get rid of horizontal gaps between stacked bars when using go.Bar()?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

This is an example from Plotly's documentation:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], y=[12, 18, 29])
])
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
```

On their website it looks like this:
[image]

Here it looks like this:
[image]

How can I get rid of the tiny gap in the `monkeys` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't **gaps**, but **lines** set with the color `'#636efa'`. You can ignore them by running:

```
fig.update_traces(marker = dict(line = dict(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')))
```

Or just:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color =  'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], y=[12, 18, 29])
])

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
# fig.update_traces(marker = dict(line = dict(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')))
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color =  'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.show()
```

Comment: I suggest to set `marker_line_width = 0` instead of `marker_line_color` to transparent